# How to load Bold Report that connects to PostGreSQL Database?

Tags: angular, asp.net-core

I have created an RDL report that connects to PostgreSQL database using a standalone bold report designer and I am able to preview the report on the designer.

But when I try to load it via ReportViewer in ASP.Net Core and angular I get the message:

**The data source ‘xyz’ has both or neither of the following: DataSourceReference and ConnectionProperties. The data source must have exactly one of these elements.**

Using the same code I tested the same using a report I designed with the same designer and connects to SQL Server Database and I am able to view the report in angular.

What is wrong with the report connecting to PostgreSQL?

What I am missing?

My ReportViewer controller in asp.net core is:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using BoldReports.Web;
using BoldReports.Web.ReportViewer;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace API.Controllers
{
    [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]
    public class ReportViewerController : Controller, IReportController
    {
        // Report viewer requires a memory cache to store the information of consecutive client request and
        // have the rendered Report Viewer information in server.
        private Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory.IMemoryCache _cache;

        // IHostingEnvironment used with sample to get the application data from wwwroot.
        private Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.IHostingEnvironment _hostingEnvironment;

        // Post action to process the report from server based json parameters and send the result back to the client.
        public ReportViewerController(Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory.IMemoryCache memoryCache,
            Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.IHostingEnvironment hostingEnvironment)
        {
            _cache = memoryCache;
            _hostingEnvironment = hostingEnvironment;
        }


        // Post action to process the report from server based json parameters and send the result back to the client.
        [HttpPost]
        public object PostReportAction([FromBody] Dictionary<string, object> jsonArray)
        {
            //Contains helper methods that help to process a Post or Get request from the Report Viewer control and return the response to the Report Viewer control
            return ReportHelper.ProcessReport(jsonArray, this, this._cache);
        }

        // Method will be called to initialize the report information to load the report with ReportHelper for processing.
        public void OnInitReportOptions(ReportViewerOptions reportOption)
        {
            reportOption.ReportModel.DataSourceCredentials
                .Add(new DataSourceCredentials
                {
                    IntegratedSecurity = false,
                    Name = "TEST",
                    ConnectionString =
                        "Host=localhost;Port=5433;Database=TESTDB;Pooling=true;",
                    UserId = "postgres",
                    Password = "p@2563262376273"
                });


            var basePath = _hostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath;
            var finalUploadDir = Path.Combine(basePath, "Resources/");
            // string basePath = _hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath;
           
            FileStream reportStream = new FileStream(finalUploadDir + reportOption.ReportModel.ReportPath,
                FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            reportOption.ReportModel.Stream = reportStream;
        }

        // Method will be called when reported is loaded with internally to start to layout process with ReportHelper.
        public void OnReportLoaded(ReportViewerOptions reportOption)
        {
        }

        //Get action for getting resources from the report
        [ActionName("GetResource")]
        [AcceptVerbs("GET")]
        // Method will be called from Report Viewer client to get the image src for Image report item.
        public object GetResource(ReportResource resource)
        {
            return ReportHelper.GetResource(resource, this, _cache);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public object PostFormReportAction()
        {
            return ReportHelper.ProcessReport(null, this, _cache);
        }
    }
}
```

The frontend code is:

```
/// <reference types="reports.all" />
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-reports',
  template: `
<bold-reportviewer
  [reportPath]="reportPath"
  [reportServiceUrl]="serviceUrl"
  id="reportViewer_Control"
  style="width: 100%;height: 950px">
</bold-reportviewer>
`,
  styleUrls: ['./reports.component.scss']
})
export class ReportsComponent implements OnInit {
  public serviceUrl: string;
  public reportPath: string;

  constructor() {
    this.serviceUrl = 'https://localhost:5001/api/ReportViewer';
    this.reportPath = 'new-report1.rdl';
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

NOTE: The same works if the report I am loading connects to SQL Server Database

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. I had to install this package into my API: BoldReports.Data.PostgreSQL and then register it on Startup class as an extension:

```
ReportConfig.DefaultSettings = new ReportSettings().RegisterExtensions(
                new List<string>
                {
                    "BoldReports.Data.PostgreSQL"
                });
```